# Using NLP to link the subjects in sentences

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am wondering if there is a way to use NLP (specifically the nltk module in python) to find similarities between the subjects within sentences. The problem is that the texts refer back to subjects within a separate sentence, and don't specifically refer to them by name (E.g. www.legaltips.org/Alabama/alabama_code/2-2-30.aspx). Any ideas or experience with this would be super helpful.

Comment: A few very specific examples might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is yes. :)

It sounds like the problem you are trying to solve is what we call anaphora or co-reference resolution in NLP - although that only refers to tracking the same referent through different sentences. You can try getting started here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dcoref.shtml

If you want to find simply similarities then this is a different problem entirely - you should let people know what kind of similarities you are talking about - semantic, syntatic, etc... and then you can get an answer (if that is your problem).

Comment: Perfect, the anaphora/co-reference was what I was looking for! Thanks a bunch